# ¿Cómo podría eliminar mis usuarios de /etc/sudoers.d/ con Ansible?

Tags: ansible

soy nuevo en Ansible y necesito ayuda para encarar un problema. Tengo un rol para crear usuarios pero el punto de falla es que al borrarlos me queda en /etc/sudoers.d la configuración de mi usuario. ¿Cómo puedo encarar el tema?

Mis usuarios se eliminan con una task usando un archivo de vars que contiene una variable llamada users_blacklist

---

```
- include_vars: vars/users.yml

- name: Delete users 
  user: 
    name: '{{ item }}' 
    state: absent
    remove: yes
  with_items: '{{ users_blacklist }}'


- name: Removing from /etc/sudoers.d if existing
  file:
    path: /etc/sudoers.d/'{{ item }}' 
    state: absent
  with_items: '{{ users_blacklist }}'
```

¿Alguien me podría dar una mano?

desde ya muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

de momento lo solucione de la siguiente manera. En mi tasks de borrar usuarios, realice un listado de los archivos del directorio que coincidan con mi users_blacklist. Después usando ese registro, mande a borrar los archivos!.

```
---

- include_vars: vars/users.yml

- name: Delete users 
  user: 
    name: '{{ item }}' 
    state: absent
    remove: yes
  with_items: '{{ users_blacklist }}'

- name: Ansible delete file /etc/sudoers.d
  find:
    paths: /etc/sudoers.d
    patterns: '{{ users_blacklist }}'
    use_regex: true
  register: files_to_delete

- name: Ansible remove file /etc/sudoers.d
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ files_to_delete.files }}"
```

Si hay otra forma, bienvenido sea!.